# "No such file or directory" error when trying to execute gcc (MinGW64) from a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, gcc, mingw-w64

Everything works fine if I directly type the following code into `cmd`:

```
cd C:\mingw-w64-810\mingw64\bin

gcc "D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.c" -o "D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.exe"
```

But I'm struggling to accomplish the same thing through the following .bat file:

```
@cd /d "C:\mingw-w64-810\mingw64\bin\"
@gcc "D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.c" –o "D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.exe"
@pause
```

I continuously get the error "No such file or directory". It is rather obvious that the space in `.\Meus Documentos\.` is the source of the problem but I don't have any idea how to correctly pass `D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.c` and `D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.exe` to gcc through a .bat file.

I was pretty sure that the above approach would work.

Comment: Certainly seems odd - what happens if you use the short directory name rather than the long?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Space is not acceptable in MingW-w64. So MingW-w64 should not be installed under any directory with space such as "Program File". So I suggest that you unintall the MinGW64 and reintall it directly under D:\

However if you really insist the current status. I may suggest you to just open a command prompt at this "D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64" place and then try

```
gcc test.c -0 test.exe
```

Though, the later suggestion is not a recommended solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is my first experience with gcc so I have copied the command from a web-page. Somehow the "-o" is being interpreted by something like "ÔÇôo".

It's possible check that out by copying and running:

```
@echo gcc "D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.c" –o "D:\Meus Documentos\MinGW64\test.exe"
@pause
```